# The exit status code '1' says something went wrong

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I am trying to export a PDF file and I am encountering the following error:

**The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [======================> ] 38% Error: Failed to load https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host not found Error: Failed to load https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host not found [============================================================] 100% Counting pages (2/6) [============================================================] Object 1 of 1 Resolving links (4/6) [============================================================] Object 1 of 1 Loading headers and footers (5/6) Printing pages (6/6) [> ] Preparing [===================> ] Page 1 of 3 [=======================================> ] Page 2 of 3 [============================================================] Page 3 of 3 Done Exit with code 1 due to network error: HostNotFoundError " stdout: "" command: D:\SETTING\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --margin-bottom "10mm" --margin-left "0" --margin-right "0" --margin-top "10mm" --orientation "landscape" --no-outline "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy651d2016ea2e03.65931215.html" "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\knp_snappy651d2016ea5753.63775246.pdf".**

this is my snappy file

```
 'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY', '"D:\SETTING\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"'),

        // 'binary'  => base_path('vendor\wemersonjanuario\wkhtmltopdf-windows\bin\64bit\wkhtmltopdf'),
        // 'binary'  => env('WKHTML_PDF_BINARY'),

        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => [],
        'env'     => [],
    ],
```

I have tried some methods but they have not been effective. Please help me

Comment: i am facing same issue